# MS ACCESS: Computing hours under night differential (time range)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Good day!

I have two fields,  **Login** and **Logout**, and I need to find out how many hours fall under night differential or from 10PM to 6AM. Both fields are formatted as **datetime** fields. So if the Login is at 10PM and the Logout is 7AM, then it should be 8 hours.

I'd prefer a query since all the other data is taken from one query - **Total Hours**, **Overtime**, etc. But I can work with an SQL or VB solution as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the night differential applies then this fairly short expression calculates it:

```
iif(
    hour(dateadd("h", 2, Logout)) < 8,
    hour(dateadd("h", 2, Logout)),
    8
) - 
iif(
    hour(dateadd("h", 2, Login)) < 8,
    hour(dateadd("h", 2, Login)),
    0
)
```

Since I think that you probably have login/logout pairs where the logout was prior to the 10pm start for differential time then you'll have to wrap this in an extra condition to trigger it and otherwise return 0. I'm thinking there might be a "cleaner" condition to use for the test. This one basically asks "Did the login and logout span the 10pm start time or the login occur during the middle of the night?"

```
iif(
    hour(Login) + 2 > hour(dateadd("h", 2, Logout)) or hour(Login) < 6,
    iif(
        hour(dateadd("h", 2, Logout)) < 8,
        hour(dateadd("h", 2, Logout)),
        8
    ) - 
    iif(
        hour(dateadd("h", 2, Login)) < 8,
        hour(dateadd("h", 2, Login)),
        0
    ),
    0
)
```

All of those literal values of 2 come from the idea of shifting the 10pm start time forward to midnight which makes the math easier. Also, I'm pretty much assuming that a login/logout is always less than 24 hours. And since you asked for hours I just used the `hour()` function. If your times don't align to exact hours and you want to calculated time difference more finely, say in minutes, then this can be easily tweaked.

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Hi! Thanks! This works great! What I did before was get the hours before 10PM and hours after 6AM which I then subtracted to the total hours. It somehow worked but it was inefficient. This is much much better!

Answer (score 0):

This will be quite convoluted to do in SQL. I believe you will need a helper function like this:

```
Public Function TimeNightHours( _
    ByVal StartTime As Date, _
    ByVal EndTime As Date) _
    As Date

    Const NightHoursFirst   As Date = #10:00:00 PM#
    Const NightHoursLast    As Date = #6:00:00 AM#

    Dim NightHours          As Date

    If StartTime = EndTime Then
        ' No hours.
    ElseIf StartTime < EndTime Then
        ' Hours don't cross Midnight.
        If StartTime < NightHoursLast Then
            ' Early night hours exist.
            If EndTime < NightHoursLast Then
                NightHours = EndTime - StartTime
            Else
                NightHours = NightHoursLast - StartTime
            End If
        End If
        If EndTime > NightHoursFirst Then
            ' Late night hours exist.
            If StartTime > NightHoursFirst Then
                NightHours = NightHours + EndTime - StartTime
            Else
                NightHours = NightHours + EndTime - NightHoursFirst
            End If
        End If
    Else
        ' Hours do cross Midnight.
        NightHours = TimeValue(CDate(1 + NightHoursLast - NightHoursFirst))
        If EndTime < NightHoursLast Then
            ' Early night hours exist.
            If StartTime > NightHoursLast Then
                NightHours = NightHours - (NightHoursLast - EndTime)
            Else
                NightHours = NightHours - (StartTime - EndTime)
            End If
        End If
        If StartTime > NightHoursFirst Then
            ' Late night hours exist.
            If EndTime < NightHoursFirst Then
                NightHours = NightHours - (StartTime - NightHoursFirst)
            Else
                NightHours = NightHours - (StartTime - EndTime)
            End If
        End If
    End If

    TimeNightHours = NightHours

End Function
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer but this gives the total hours from time of Login to time of Logout.

Comment: No. It returns the night hours.